# Madhyamika and Ajativada and anuttara of advaita vedanta and kashmir shaivism

Tags: philosophy, advaita, kashmiri-shaivism

Is the madhyamika deconstruction of reality that nothing arises and nothing ceases the same as ajativada of gaudapada and anuttara of abhinavagupta? in madhyamika production is never established and momentariness is even a false relative reality and a Upaya(skillful teaching that isn't true).

nothing ceases.nothing arises.production/arising and Ceasing-destruction are not established.is this the same as ajativada or anuttara,if yes..why?if not..why?

Comment: Abhinavaguptas ideology accepts the creation as REAL and out of free will (swatantrya) of shiva shakti principles

Comment: it is a question of semantics.this reality is a relative reality per abhinavagupta.thats what madhyamika says too.in madhyamika,there is no production or creation at all.only the 5 wisdom lights reified mistakenly as 5 elements exist.only conventionally.in KS,only Samvit exists so creation and production are also relative realities.nothing actually new is being created.and I think you should study madhyamika philosophy more than just redherrings and strawmen.

Comment: here - https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey

Comment: I would think the main difference is that advaita vedanta is a Cittamatra viewpoint,whereas in madhyamika consciousness is manifold and unique to every sentient being but also is just an element among other elements.advaita believes consciousness is the source of these elements.

Comment: @johnyman that is not correct understanding of KS a